# Asp.net The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com'

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to let user in my website to register and log in to my site through Facebook,

On the previous hosting, the code worked very well, but when i transferred to the new hosting I get this error "The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com'".

I googled the problem but there are no obvious solution.

I am using Asp.net.

the error come from this line of code :

```
string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me");
```

Comment: Your new host is blocking the call. If it cannot be resolved.. it means the DNS lookup failed for it (it shouldn't.. because it resolves fine for me).

Comment: how can I unblock the call??

Comment: You can try calling it by IP instead of domain..

Comment: I didn't write any explicit url, the url called implicitly when I used the FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me") function.

Comment: Is there any configuration for this? Say.. in your web config?

Comment: No, there are no any configration for this in web.config.

Comment: what the configurations should be in web.config?